# JQGrid "Inline" Insert functionality

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid, insert, inline-editing

I am new to JQGrid.I am using inline editing of Jqgrid. Functionality I am trying to achieve is
1. add new row in JQGrid 
2. then press "enter" key.
3. This should call a method in .cs page (server side code).
Issue is I tried Keydown event,addRow functionality but I can only **set**  editurl:"\ \functionname" but cannot call method after pressing "enter"Key.
For example when we edit some data onrow  click it allows us to call server side method after  pressing "Enter" key. on insert button i need to achieve same functionality .

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqgrid inline add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989471/jqgrid-inline-add)

Answer (score 0):

try this

keys:true

Read the wiki for usage

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Comment: Hi Kris,

keys:true option is only available for editrow.It does not work for insert.